# 400. That’s an error. The redirect URI in the request: did not match a registered redirect URI

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I want to upload file to google drive

I have used following code but I get following error message:

> The redirect URI in the request:
>   http://localhost/upload_gd2/google-api/examples/user-example.php did
>   not match a registered redirect URI.

Code:

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
include_once "templates/base.php";
session_start();

require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../src/Google/autoload.php');

/************************************************
  ATTENTION: Fill in these values! Make sure
  the redirect URI is to this page, e.g:
  http://localhost:8080/user-example.php
 ************************************************/
 $client_id = '***************.apps.googleusercontent.com';
 $client_secret = '**************************************';
 $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/upload_gd2/google-api/examples/user-example.php';

/************************************************
  Make an API request on behalf of a user. In
  this case we need to have a valid OAuth 2.0
  token for the user, so we need to send them
  through a login flow. To do this we need some
  information from our API console project.
 ************************************************/
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener");

/************************************************
  When we create the service here, we pass the
  client to it. The client then queries the service
  for the required scopes, and uses that when
  generating the authentication URL later.
 ************************************************/
$service = new Google_Service_Urlshortener($client);

/************************************************
  If we're logging out we just need to clear our
  local access token in this case
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
}

/************************************************
  If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
  we need to exchange that with the authenticate()
  function. We store the resultant access token
  bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

/************************************************
  If we have an access token, we can make
  requests, else we generate an authentication URL.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

/************************************************
  If we're signed in and have a request to shorten
  a URL, then we create a new URL object, set the
  unshortened URL, and call the 'insert' method on
  the 'url' resource. Note that we re-store the
  access_token bundle, just in case anything
  changed during the request - the main thing that
  might happen here is the access token itself is
  refreshed if the application has offline access.
 ************************************************/
if ($client->getAccessToken() && isset($_GET['url'])) {
  $url = new Google_Service_Urlshortener_Url();
  $url->longUrl = $_GET['url'];
  $short = $service->url->insert($url);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

echo pageHeader("User Query - URL Shortener");
if (strpos($client_id, "googleusercontent") == false) {
  echo missingClientSecretsWarning();
  exit;
}
?>
<div class="box">
  <div class="request">
<?php 
if (isset($authUrl)) {
  echo "<a class='login' href='" . $authUrl . "'>Connect Me!</a>";
} else {
  echo <<<END
    <form id="url" method="GET" action="{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}">
      <input name="url" class="url" type="text">
      <input type="submit" value="Shorten">
    </form>
    <a class='logout' href='?logout'>Logout</a>
END;
}
?>
  </div>

  <div class="shortened">
<?php
if (isset($short)) {
  var_dump($short);
}
?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
echo pageFooter(__FILE__);
```

[image]

Redirect url while registering in google console is

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The redirect URI in the request does not match the URI you have shown in your Authorized redirect URIs. The URI you send in the request must be in your auth'd URIs, or you get this error.

Comment: can u please let me know what URI should i enter as far as my project url is concerned.

Comment: From looking at your code, you should enter the URI stored in the $redirect_uri variable into the Authorized redirect URIs part of the google console. However, if you look at the error Google gave you, this doesn't match with the $redirect_uri variable. I'm guessing your using someone elses code to help you access Google Drive, so I'd suggest going through their example and matching your redirect uri's with theres.

Comment: This is the redirect uri i'm using http://localhost:8080/upload_gd2/google-api/examples/user-example.php and the author of the code says to use htttp://localhost:8080/user-example.php as redirect uri.  I have appended project path to it but the error is same. This is the eg. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client you pleaase check this example.

Comment: You need to put that redirect uri in the Authorized redirect URI's part in the Google console.

Comment: but my project path is different and i my project also i have to enter the same  redirect uri that i entered in Authorized redirect URI's part in the Google console

Comment: Can u please help to solve my issue by checking the above example.

Comment: I don't have the time to read through that, learn how it works, then work out where you went wrong. What I'd suggest doing is use the example and change the redirect URI's (and other stuff to make it relate to your account) to the ones you want to use. Keep trying till the error goes away, then implement into your system